# Ignore unkown values in Keras model.fit

Tags: python, keras, loss-function

I'm trying to learn my computer to play Snake using deep learning in Keras. My model tries to predict the total reward each of the four actions will give. Because the agent only takes one action, only the true value of one of the four predicted rewards is known. This causes problems when calling model.fit, because it wants the true values for each output. I've tried to implement a loss function that ignores the other values, but didn't succeed.

Does anyone know how to do this right?

Comment: Please dhow us how you implemented it and describe how it failed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it using the following loss function:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    diff = y_true - y_pred
    max_diff = K.max(diff, axis=1)
    return K.square(max_diff)
```

and setting each unknown value to a very low and negative one.